# Generating all possible combinations from a list of lists

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, artificial-intelligence

I have the following lists:

```
[[a,b,c],[b],[d,a,b,e],[a,c]]
```

This list represents a mini-world in a puzzle problem. In this example the world contains 4 piles of objects stacked on-top of each other. I can only move the top object and place it on-top of some other stack. The letters represent a type of object, for example a might be a rock and b a ball. 
I need to generate all possible states that can exist for this mini-world. Im trying to do this in python but don't know how to implement it.

Comment: You multiple objects of the same type. Do you need to distinguish between the individual objects, or just types of objects?

Comment: Individual objects are important.

Comment: For the case `[ [a], [b], [] ]`, what are the possible states? Are you trying to find "all valid states from current state using the available move"? Then you need to define clearly what are the moves available, and how do you represent the stack (is it represented as a list from top-to-bottom or from bottom-to-top?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itertools.combinations_with_replacement](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) with list comprehension:

```
import itertools
ll = [['a','b','c'],['b'],['d','a','b','e'],['a','c']]
print [list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(item,len(item))) for item in ll]
```

It gives the combinations for each element in list of lists.

Output:

```
 [[('a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'c'), ('b', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'c')], 
 [('b',)], 
 [('d', 'd', 'd', 'd'), ('d', 'd', 'd', 'a'), ('d', 'd', 'd', 'b'), ('d', 'd', 'd', 'e'), ('d', 'd', 'a', 'a'), ('d', 'd', 'a', 'b'), ('d', 'd', 'a', 'e'), ('d', 'd', 'b', 'b'), ('d', 'd', 'b', 'e'), ('d', 'd', 'e', 'e'), ('d', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('d', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('d', 'a', 'a', 'e'), ('d', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('d', 'a', 'b', 'e'), ('d', 'a', 'e', 'e'), ('d', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('d', 'b', 'b', 'e'), ('d', 'b', 'e', 'e'), ('d', 'e', 'e', 'e'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'e'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'e'), ('a', 'a', 'e', 'e'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'e'), ('a', 'b', 'e', 'e'), ('a', 'e', 'e', 'e'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'e'), ('b', 'b', 'e', 'e'), ('b', 'e', 'e', 'e'), ('e', 'e', 'e', 'e')], 
 [('a', 'a'), ('a', 'c'), ('c', 'c')]]
```

If you would like to avoid duplicate same element in a combination, you can use [itertools.permutation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
 [list(itertools.permutations(item,len(item))) for item in ll]
```

Output:

```
[[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'a')], 
[('b',)], 
[('d', 'a', 'b', 'e'), ('d', 'a', 'e', 'b'), ('d', 'b', 'a', 'e'), ('d', 'b', 'e', 'a'), ('d', 'e', 'a', 'b'), ('d', 'e', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'd', 'b', 'e'), ('a', 'd', 'e', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'd', 'e'), ('a', 'b', 'e', 'd'), ('a', 'e', 'd', 'b'), ('a', 'e', 'b', 'd'), ('b', 'd', 'a', 'e'), ('b', 'd', 'e', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'd', 'e'), ('b', 'a', 'e', 'd'), ('b', 'e', 'd', 'a'), ('b', 'e', 'a', 'd'), ('e', 'd', 'a', 'b'), ('e', 'd', 'b', 'a'), ('e', 'a', 'd', 'b'), ('e', 'a', 'b', 'd'), ('e', 'b', 'd', 'a'), ('e', 'b', 'a', 'd')], 
[('a', 'c'), ('c', 'a')]]
```

Comment: Not really correct i think. A minimum case would be two piles with one item in each. [[a],[b]], now all states that can exist in this world is as follows: [([a],[b]),([b,a],[]),([],[a,b])].

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a recursive generator. The logic works like this:

- yield the current state
- find all the states that are one move away from this state
- recursively apply the logic to those

There is one problem with this: it is possible to come back to the starting point (move 'c' right one stack, then move 'c' left one stack), which would lead to an infinite recursion. I get around this by only considering moves in one direction, but the more general approach is to keep track of all the states you've seen already, and bail out if you arrive back at one.

This is what I have:

```
def shuffle_stacks(state):
    '''
    shuffle_stacks([[a], [b, c]]) -> 
       [[a, b], [c]], 
       [[a], [c, b]], 
       [[], [c, b, a]]

    yield all possible states that can be given by moving an item off
    the top of a sublist to the top of any other sublist, recursively.

    Currently only moves items to the right of their starting point.

    '''
    yield state

    # Find all the possible states we can be in if we move
    # one item off the top of a stack to any stack to its right
    # Apply recursively to each such state

    for i, source in enumerate(state):
        unchanged_state = state[:i]
        targets = state[i+1:]
        source = source[:]

        if not source or not targets:
            continue

            item = source.pop()
            for j, target in enumerate(targets):
                # Copy mutables to isolate changes
                target = target[:]
                targets = targets[:]
                targets[j] = target

                target.append(item)
                next_state = unchanged_state + [source] + targets
                yield from shuffle_stacks(next_state)
```

Note that `yield from` doesn't exist in Python 2.7, but if upgrading to at least 3.3 isn't an option for you, you can replace it with a loop:

```
for new_state in shuffle_stacks(next_state):
     yield new_state
```

Comment: Nice thanks! This works. Will try expanding it and post my code.